# Returning multiple (if all) objects.get in django then outputting to a template

Tags: python, django

I am trying to search through the database of users returning matches of the search query, then I get this data and output it to a html. It works but I need to do this for multiple objects sometimes where this can get quite convoluted.

views.py

```
def search_index(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SearchForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            searchquery = form.cleaned_data['searchquery']
            try:
                found = (CustomUser.objects.get(username__icontains=searchquery))
                foundname = (found.username)
                foundimage = (found.docfile)
                founddate = (found.date_joined)
                foundid = (found.id)
                # Redirect to the document list after POST
                return render(request, 'search_found.html', {'foundname':foundname,'foundimage':foundimage, 'founddate':founddate, 'foundid':foundid})
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
    else:
        form = SearchForm() # A empty, unbound form

    return render(request, 'search_index.html', {'form':form})
```

forms.py

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
searchquery = forms.CharField(label="Search for a username", max_length=100)
```

search_found.html

```
{% extends "_base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<html>
  <div class="foundbox">
    <button class="add-friend">Add Friend</button>
    <button onclick="window.location.href='../profile/{{ foundid }}'"      class="show-profile">Profile</button>
    <div class="foundimage">
      <div class="foundimage_container">
        <img class="foundimage_container" src="../{{ foundimage }}"     onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='../static/users/default.gif';"></img>
     </div>
   </div>
   <h2 class="foundtext">{{foundname}}</h2>
   <p class="founddate">Join date: {{founddate}}</p>
  </div>
</html>

{% endblock %}
```

please mind the formatting.

Comment: _but I need to do this for multiple objects_ Do you mean multiple objects of the same type, or of different types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you'll need to change .get() to .filter() to return a collection

```
users = (CustomUser.objects.filter(username__icontains=searchquery))
```

Secondly, you will need to pass users into your view context and then wrap the html you want to repeat in a for loop:

```
{% for user in users %}
```

The final would look something like

def search_index(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SearchForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        searchquery = form.cleaned_data['searchquery']
        try:
            users = CustomUser.objects.filter(username__icontains=searchquery)
            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return render(request, 'search_found.', {'users': users})
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
else:
    form = SearchForm() # A empty, unbound form

return render(request, 'search_index.html', {'form':form})
```

And your view

```
{% extends "_base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<html>
  {% for user in users %}
  <div class="foundbox">
    <button class="add-friend">Add Friend</button>
    <button onclick="window.location.href='../profile/{{ user.id }}'"      class="show-profile">Profile</button>
    <div class="foundimage">
      <div class="foundimage_container">
        <img class="foundimage_container" src="../{{ user.docfile }}"     onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='../static/users/default.gif';"></img>
     </div>
   </div>
   <h2 class="foundtext">{{user.username}}</h2>
   <p class="founddate">Join date: {{user.date_joined}}</p>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</html>

{% endblock %}
```